# Move constructors and segmentation faults

Tags: c++

I have a struct X that contains a pointer to an array:

```
int global_id = 0;

struct X
{
        int id; 
        char *p; 

        X(int id_) : p(new char[1024]), id(id_)
        {   
                printf("Constructing X (id %d)\n", id);
        }   

        X() : p(new char[1024]), id(global_id++)
        {   
                printf("Constructing X (id %d)\n", id);
        }   

        ~X()
        {   
                delete [] p;
                printf("Destroying X (id %d) and array\n", id);
        }   

        X(X const & rhs) : id(global_id++)
        {   
                printf("X copy constructor (%d -> new %d) \n", rhs.id, id);
                memcpy(p, rhs.p, sizeof(p));
        }   

        X& operator=(X const & rhs)
        {   
                printf("X copy assignment (%d -> %d) \n", rhs.id, id);
                memcpy(p, rhs.p, sizeof(p));
        }   

        X(X && rhs) : id(global_id++)
        {   
                printf("X move constructor (%d -> new %d) \n", rhs.id, id);
                swap(p, rhs.p);
        }   

        X& operator=(X && rhs)
        {   
                printf("X move assignment (%d -> %d) \n", rhs.id, id);
                swap(p, rhs.p);
        }   

};
```

I create a function foo() that constructs a local X and returns it. But it causes a segfault:

```
X foo()
{
        X local_x;
        return local_x;
}

main()
{
        printf("\n1\n");
        X x;

        printf("\n2\n");
        x = foo();
}
```

My expectation is:
1) local_x is constructed, printing "Constructing X (id 1)"

2) local_x is moved into a temporary object to be returned, printing "X move constructor (1 -> new 2)"

3) local_x is destroyed, printing "Destroying X (id 1)"

4) the temporary is moved into x, printing "X move assignment (2 -> 0)"

Instead, a segfault happens in the destructor of local_x:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff74ab428 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:54
#1  0x00007ffff74ad02a in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2  0x00007ffff74ed7ea in __libc_message (do_abort=do_abort@entry=2, 
    fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff76062e0 "*** Error in `%s': %s: 0x%s ***\n")
    at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:175
#3  0x00007ffff74f9ae8 in malloc_printerr (ar_ptr=0x0, ptr=<optimized out>, 
    str=0x7ffff7606308 "munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer", action=<optimized out>)
    at malloc.c:5004
#4  munmap_chunk (p=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:2840
#5  __GI___libc_free (mem=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:2961
#6  0x0000000000400c8d in X::~X (this=0x7fffffffe220, __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
    at ref.cpp:27
#7  0x000000000040098e in foo () at ref.cpp:59
#8  0x0000000000400a4c in main () at ref.cpp:86
(gdb) f 6
#6  0x0000000000400c8d in X::~X (this=0x7fffffffe220, __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
    at ref.cpp:27
27                      delete [] p;
(gdb) p id
$1 = 1
```

The following is printed to stdout:

```
1
Constructing X (id 0)
2
Constructing X (id 1)
X move constructor (1 -> new 2) 
*** Error in `/home/spm/code/ref': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000400edd ***
```

Why am I getting a segfault? p should be a pointer to the array allocated using new[] in the temporary's constructor, so the delete[] should work correctly.

Comment: Tell your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) what your copy constructor and assignment operator are doing.

Comment: Don't use manual memory allocations for this. Use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) (or possibly [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)) instead and you can live by [the rule of zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero)

Comment: `sizeof(p)` is `sizeof(char*)`, not the size of the buffer pointed to by `p`.

Comment: @juanchopanza good catch - it should be 1024 instead of sizeof, but that shouldn't be causing this bug because the copy constructor is never called.

Comment: `p` is uninitialized in your move-constructor.

Comment: @user1299784 I don't think that's the *only* bug that juanchopanza was thinking about. Remember that a copy-constructor is just a normal constructor, that has to construct and initialize a brand-new object just like any other constructor.

Comment: You have a whole lot of bugs in your code. But the rubber duck is a good listener.

Comment: @juanchopanza I initialized p in the copy and move constructors, and the stacktrace no longer happens. What other bugs do I have?

Comment: You actually do not want to allocate any arrays in the move constructor. Just ensure that this->p is set to something reasonable (i.e. nullptr) before you do the swap.

Comment: @user1299784 You hadn't in the original code you posted.

Comment: Please don't edit your questions to remove the problems you had. How are we supposed to understand what was your question and its proper answer?

Comment: You updated the code in the question, but now you’re asking why it has a segfault when it doesn’t. Some programmer dude’s advice was good (though, depending on your real use case, a `unique_ptr` might be better), but if you want to do manual memory management for some reason I can’t see any further bugs.

Comment: By the way, why is my post getting downvoted? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @user1299784 Your question is hard to track and understand because of your edits. It'd be alright if the whole point was to make _your_ program work, but that's not the format of StackExchange. Your question is supposed to help others who might face similar problems

Answer (score 1):

Your copy constructor and move constructors don’t have `p` in their initialization lists, leaving them uninitialized. For your copy constructor, this means you `memcpy` a bunch of bytes to some random point in memory, which is undefined. For your move constructor, this means that when you `swap`, you leave `rhs.p` in an uninitialized state, which you then `delete[]`.

For your copy constructor, you probably want to call `new` just like you did in the default constructor. For your move constructor, there’s no need to allocate memory; you can just initialize `p` to `nullptr` (which is safe to `delete[]`).